# sklearn - How to retrieve PCA components and explained variance from inside a Pipeline passed to GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I am using GridSearchCV with a pipeline as follows:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(
    Pipeline([
        ('reduce_dim', PCA()),
        ('classify', RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs = -1))
        ]),
    param_grid=[
        {
            'reduce_dim__n_components': range(0.7,0.9,0.1),
            'classify__n_estimators': range(10,50,5),
            'classify__max_features': ['auto', 0.2],
            'classify__min_samples_leaf': [40,50,60],
            'classify__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']
        }
    ],
    cv=5, scoring='f1')

grid.fit(X,y)
```

How do I now retrieve PCA details like `components` and `explained_variance` from the `grid.best_estimator_` model?

Furthermore, I also want to save the `best_estimator_` to a file using pickle and later load it. How do I retrieve the PCA details from this loaded estimator? I suspect it will be the same as above.

Comment: I don't get your PCA grid part: `'reduce_dim__n_components': range(0.7,0.9,0.1)` what are the range of values here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grid.best_estimator_` is to access the pipeline with the best parameters.

Now use [`named_steps[]`attribute](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) to access the internal estimators of the pipeline.

So `grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['reduce_dim']` will give you the `pca` object. Now you can simply use this to access the `components_` and `explained_variance_` attibutes for this pca object like this:

`grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['reduce_dim'].components_` 
`grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['reduce_dim'].explained_variance_`

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a bunch!