# Multiple dimensionality reduction techniques with pipeline and GridSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, hyperparameters, dimensionality-reduction

we all know the common approach to define a pipeline with a dimensionality reduction technique and then a model for training and testing. Then we can apply the GridSearchCv for hyperparameter tuning.

```
grid = GridSearchCV(
Pipeline([
    ('reduce_dim', PCA()),
    ('classify', RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs = -1))
    ]),
param_grid=[
    {
        'reduce_dim__n_components': range(0.7,0.9,0.1),
        'classify__n_estimators': range(10,50,5),
        'classify__max_features': ['auto', 0.2],
        'classify__min_samples_leaf': [40,50,60],
        'classify__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']
    }
],
cv=5, scoring='f1')
grid.fit(X,y)
```

I can understand the above code.

Now i was going through the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_compare_reduction.html) today and there i found one part code which is little bit strange.

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    # the reduce_dim stage is populated by the param_grid
    ('reduce_dim', 'passthrough'),                        # How does this work??
    ('classify', LinearSVC(dual=False, max_iter=10000))
])

N_FEATURES_OPTIONS = [2, 4, 8]
C_OPTIONS = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
param_grid = [
    {
        'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()],
        'reduce_dim__n_components': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,   ### No PCA is used..??
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
    {
        'reduce_dim': [SelectKBest(chi2)],
        'reduce_dim__k': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
]
reducer_labels = ['PCA', 'NMF', 'KBest(chi2)']

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, n_jobs=1, param_grid=param_grid)
X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
grid.fit(X, y)
```

1. First of all while defining a pipeline, **it used a string 'passthrough' instead of a object.**

   ````
       ('reduce_dim', 'passthrough'),  ```
   ````
2. Then while defining different dimensionality reduction technique for the grid search, it used a different strategy. How does `[PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()]` this work ?

   ```
           'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()],
           'reduce_dim__n_components': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,  # here
   ```

Please Someone explain the code to me .

**Solved** - in one line, the order is `['PCA', 'NMF', 'KBest(chi2)']`

**Courtesy of** - *seralouk* (see answer below)

For *Reference* If someone looks for more details
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46800147/12210002) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42266737/12210002) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997797/12210002)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is equivalent as far as I know.**

---

In the documentation you have this:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    # the reduce_dim stage is populated by the param_grid
    ('reduce_dim', 'passthrough'),
    ('classify', LinearSVC(dual=False, max_iter=10000))
])

N_FEATURES_OPTIONS = [2, 4, 8]
C_OPTIONS = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
param_grid = [
    {
        'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()],
        'reduce_dim__n_components': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
    {
        'reduce_dim': [SelectKBest(chi2)],
        'reduce_dim__k': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
]
```

Initially we have `('reduce_dim', 'passthrough'),` and then `'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()]`

The definition of the PCA is done in the second line.

---

**You could define alternatively:**

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    # the reduce_dim stage is populated by the param_grid
    ('reduce_dim', PCA(iterated_power=7)),
    ('classify', LinearSVC(dual=False, max_iter=10000))
])

N_FEATURES_OPTIONS = [2, 4, 8]
C_OPTIONS = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
param_grid = [
    {
        'reduce_dim__n_components': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
    {
        'reduce_dim': [SelectKBest(chi2)],
        'reduce_dim__k': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
]
```

Comment: So, later it assigns a object in the place of passthrough. but ```'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()]``` how does this work? Does Grid search try one by one ?

Comment: It uses both ! To reduce the dimensions

Comment: So it will first apply PCA and then NMF to the dataset. Then it will check with ```SelectKBest(chi2)``` . Which ever gets the higher score, it will select that..right ?

Comment: Exactly. the order is `['PCA', 'NMF', 'KBest(chi2)']`